# Run callback in the function only if there is no new calls of the function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, closures

I have a component in project which accepts a function with callback param. On change of this component this function calls inside. But here is problem, we get some data asynchronously on every change with `async` `await` function and after we get some data we do callback. So, on second change, I can see callback call with old data. Standard debounce doesn't work here because of `async`.

Here is my fast solution with closure:

```
function doOnlyLastFunction(fnc) {
    let id = 0;
    const isLast = (currentId) => () => currentId === id;
    return (...args) => {
        id++;
        fnc.call(this, ...args, isLast);
    };
}
```

in runtime shortly:

```
let closure = null;
function handler(data, cb) {
    if (!closure) {
        closure = doOnlyLastFunction(async (data, cb, isLast) => {
            //await some promises
            if (isLast()) {
                cb(result); //cb with data
            }         
        });
    }
    closure(data, cb);
}
```

I this this is bad solution and I can't change logic on the top level. Is there a way to optimize this logic?

Comment: What do you mean by "*I can't change logic on the top level.*"?

Comment: @Bergi i can't rewrite the component logic and the logic of the promises

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving the `isLast()` check inside the callback itself that your `fnc` is calling:

```
function doOnlyLastFunction(fn) {
    let id = 0;
    return function(...args) {
        const currentId = ++id;
        const cb = args.pop();
        fn.call(this, ...args, function(...results) {
            if (currentId === id)
                cb(...results);
        });
    };
}
```

Also you don't need to lazily initialise your `closure` variable from inside `handler`. Just go for

```
const handler = doOnlyLastFunction(async (data, cb) => {
    //await some promises
    cb(result); //cb with data
});
```